# Timeout issues when using latest Wordpress Docker image

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

I keep my Wordpress site and plugins up-to-date, but haven't updated the Docker image in a while.
Wordpress is running on 5.8.1/PHP 7.4.13 (as seen from site health).
The Docker image I am using (official Wordpress) was built on Wordpress 5.6/PHP 7.4.13.

When I pull the latest image: "wordpress:5.8.1-php7.4-apache" which contains PHP 7.4.23 and start a container using this image and the same compose file, the website  times out after a short while.

In the container logs, the following error can been seen:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30+2 seconds exceeded (terminated) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2126
```

I am also seeing this error in site health:

```
The REST API request failed due to an error.
Error: cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 1091184004065 milliseconds (http_request_failed)
```

I already disabled all plugins, but that did not solve the issue.
I can easily roll-back by starting the old container based on the old image, but I would like to update the docker image (being the backend) as well.

What would be the best approach to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Is the mysql database for the site inside the same docker image? If so, I would hit up the logs for mysql server inside the container as it sounds like it isn't running. If the mysql database is hosted in another container or externally, then I would bet this is a networking issue between your container and wherever you database is at. I'm no wordpress expert though, so grain of salt. It just smells like one issue or the other.

Comment: Mysql is hosted in a different container on the same host, both old and new containers use the same network/database settings, there is no firewall in between. If there is an issue connecting to the database I assume I would have seen that in the logs.

Comment: Could the database be taking some time to respond? I'm wondering if there are steps wordpress takes upon coming online to update the database for the new version where perhaps it needs more than 32 seconds to respond?

Comment: Wouldn't the database be already updated by Wordpress running in the container being auto-updated? I assumed by updating the Docker image I was just updating the backend, not Wordpress itself or the database.